# Salesforce Marketing Cloud -> exit criteria with condition related to entry date on the journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, custom, data-designer

It is possible to define the exit criteria with a condition over the entry date of the customer?
Example:
Order Date of the customer is AFTER the entry date of the customer in that journey.

I imagine that we can do one workaround updating one Data Extension every time one customer enter a journey with the current time and relate that DE in the Data Designer to be available. But honestly i like to avoid this option, it pollutes the data designer with unnecessary information, i was imagining something like a custom function to introduce in the exit criteria.

Anyone knows a solution for this case?

Comment: If you have Order Date as a date field on your data extension, I think you can add a decision split to your journey to see if the order date is after the entry date. Yet, the tricky part is getting the entry date which you might have adding another date field which gets the date when the record is created in the data extension. Simply, Now() function when the record is created.

Comment: Hi Selim, That solution works with an update contact activity that will update the DE Audience of the journey, it is workaround solution, but i was hoping that SFMC has some built in solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

If your record is added to the data extension right before entering the journey, you can use a CreatedDate field set as nullable and use the current date as default.

Alternatively, upon entering the journey you can use an Update Contact Activity with the current timestamp and use that attribute to compare against in the exit criteria.

Either way, you'll need that entry date in your journey DE to compare it against your order date.